# npm install errors - which one to focus on?

Tags: node.js

So I do

```
sudo npm install -g sails
```

and I get

```
> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/bufferutil.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/validation.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/bufferutil.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/bufferutil.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/validation.node
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Release/validation.node] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:269:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.5.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/sails-hook-sockets/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1
/usr/local/bin/sails -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/bin/sails.js
sails@0.11.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails
├── sails-build-dictionary@0.10.1
├── cookie@0.1.2
├── cookie-signature@1.0.4
├── grunt-contrib-copy@0.5.0
├── mock-res@0.1.0
├── mock-req@0.1.0
├── connect-flash@0.1.1
├── commander@2.1.0
├── sails-stringfile@0.3.2
├── merge-defaults@0.1.4
├── colors@0.6.2
├── pluralize@0.0.12
├── grunt-sails-linker@0.9.6
├── node-uuid@1.4.3
├── async@0.9.2
├── uid-safe@1.1.0 (base64-url@1.2.1, native-or-bluebird@1.1.2)
├── grunt-contrib-concat@0.3.0
├── reportback@0.1.9 (switchback@1.1.3)
├── grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0 (rimraf@2.2.8)
├── semver@2.2.1
├── rc@0.5.5 (ini@1.3.4, strip-json-comments@0.1.3, deep-extend@0.2.11, minimist@0.0.10)
├── fs-extra@0.8.1 (jsonfile@1.1.1, rimraf@2.2.8, ncp@0.4.2, mkdirp@0.3.5)
├── method-override@2.3.5 (methods@1.1.1, vary@1.0.1, parseurl@1.3.0, debug@2.2.0)
├── ejs-locals@1.0.2
├── ejs@0.8.8
├── grunt-cli@0.1.13 (findup-sync@0.1.3, nopt@1.0.10, resolve@0.3.1)
├── grunt-sync@0.0.8 (promised-io@0.3.3)
├── sails-disk@0.10.8 (waterline-errors@0.10.1, async@0.2.10, waterline-criteria@0.11.2, waterline-cursor@0.0.6)
├── glob@3.2.11 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.3.0)
├── i18n@0.5.0 (sprintf@0.1.5, mustache@2.1.3, debug@2.2.0)
├── express@3.16.0 (basic-auth@1.0.0, merge-descriptors@0.0.2, escape-html@1.0.1, fresh@0.2.2, range-parser@1.0.0, vary@0.1.0, media-typer@0.2.0, parseurl@1.2.0, methods@1.1.0, buffer-crc32@0.2.3, depd@0.4.4, debug@1.0.4, commander@1.3.2, proxy-addr@1.0.1, send@0.8.1, mkdirp@0.5.0)
├── grunt-contrib-coffee@0.10.1 (chalk@0.4.0, coffee-script@1.7.1)
├── grunt-contrib-cssmin@0.9.0 (chalk@0.4.0, clean-css@2.1.8, maxmin@0.1.0)
├── grunt-contrib-jst@0.6.0 (chalk@0.4.0, grunt-lib-contrib@0.7.1)
├── skipper@0.5.7 (string_decoder@0.10.31, dot-access@1.0.0, async@1.4.2, skipper-disk@0.5.4, colors@1.1.2, semver@5.0.3, debug@2.2.0, multiparty@3.2.10)
├── include-all@0.1.6 (underscore.string@2.3.1)
├── prompt@0.2.14 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.7, winston@0.8.3, utile@0.2.1)
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── captains-log@0.11.11 (rc@0.3.5, lodash@2.4.1)
├── grunt-contrib-uglify@0.4.1 (chalk@0.4.0, maxmin@0.1.0, uglify-js@2.4.24)
├── sails-util@0.10.6 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, switchback@1.1.3, optimist@0.6.1, underscore.string@2.3.3)
├── connect@2.25.0 (response-time@2.0.0, pause@0.0.1, fresh@0.2.2, on-headers@0.0.0, basic-auth-connect@1.0.0, media-typer@0.2.0, parseurl@1.2.0, bytes@1.0.0, serve-favicon@2.0.1, vhost@2.0.0, cookie-parser@1.3.2, depd@0.4.4, qs@1.0.2, finalhandler@0.1.0, connect-timeout@1.2.2, method-override@2.1.3, debug@1.0.4, morgan@1.2.3, csurf@1.4.1, type-is@1.3.2, errorhandler@1.1.1, compression@1.0.11, serve-static@1.5.4, express-session@1.7.6, multiparty@3.3.1, body-parser@1.6.7, serve-index@1.1.6)
├── grunt-contrib-watch@0.5.3 (tiny-lr@0.0.4, gaze@0.4.3)
├── grunt@0.4.2 (dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3, which@1.0.9, eventemitter2@0.4.14, getobject@0.1.0, async@0.1.22, hooker@0.2.3, rimraf@2.0.3, nopt@1.0.10, exit@0.1.2, minimatch@0.2.14, glob@3.1.21, lodash@0.9.2, coffee-script@1.3.3, underscore.string@2.2.1, iconv-lite@0.2.11, findup-sync@0.1.3, js-yaml@2.0.5)
├── sails-generate@0.12.3 (sails-generate-api@0.10.0, sails-generate-gruntfile@0.10.10, async@0.2.10, sails-generate-adapter@0.10.5, sails-generate-generator@0.10.11, sails-generate-views-jade@0.10.3, sails-generate-views@0.10.5, sails-generate-sails.io.js@0.11.7, sails-generate-backend@0.12.2, sails-generate-frontend@0.11.5, sails-generate-model@0.10.10, sails-generate-controller@0.10.8, sails-generate-new@0.10.21)
├── waterline@0.10.26 (bluebird@2.9.34, async@1.2.1, deep-diff@0.3.2, switchback@1.1.3, waterline-criteria@0.11.2, lodash@3.9.3, waterline-schema@0.1.18)
├── anchor@0.10.5
├── express-handlebars@1.0.3 (graceful-fs@3.0.8, promise@5.0.0, semver@3.0.1, glob@4.5.3, handlebars@2.0.0)
├── grunt-contrib-less@0.11.1 (chalk@0.4.0, async@0.2.10, maxmin@0.1.0, less@1.7.5)
└── sails-hook-sockets@0.11.25 (semver@4.3.6, machinepack-urls@3.1.1, socket.io@1.3.7, socket.io-client@1.3.7)
```

and I weep, because I get these same types of errors when I do

```
yo meanjs
```

What is wrong with my system? (macbook air 10.10.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

every error message says "ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5". maybe try installing it?

Comment: ok that told me what to focus on, and allowed me to find the root cause of all this silliness. Thanks

Comment: yeah, it seems to be specific to macos. i'm on ubuntu, so can't really help further.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the latest upgrade from Apple (Command Line Tools (OS X 10.10) for XCode) caused the break.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/2933

running

```
cd /usr/local/lib
sudo ln -s ../../lib/libSystem.B.dylib libgcc_s.10.5.dylib
```

fixes the issue.

Comment: Had this exact issue and this worked for me in one shot when trying to install karma.